# Finding a bug in getTotalX function. Python

Tags: python

Recently I was asked the following question in an interview to be programmed via python:

> The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being considered
>   The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array
>   These numbers are referred to as being between the two arrays. You must determine how many such numbers exist.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of n, the number of elements in array a, and m, the number of elements in array b. 
>   The second line contains n distinct space-separated integers describing a0, a1, ... an-1. 
>   The third line contains m distinct space-separated integers describing b0, b1, ... bn-1.
>
> Constraints
>
> - n,m in the range 1,10
> - ai in the range 1,100
> - bi in the range 1,100
>
> Output Format
>
> Print the number of integers that are considered to be between a and b.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 2 3
> 2 4
> 16 32 96
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> - 2 and 4 divide evenly into 4, 8, 12 and 16.
> - 4, 8 and 16 divide evenly into 16, 32, 96.
>
> 4, 8 and 16 are the only three numbers for which each element of A is a factor and each is a factor of all elements of B.

This is the code that I wrote (I only had to complete the function 'getTotalX'. The remaining code already existed):

[Code. The function body getTotalX is what I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qILma.jpg)

However, it seems, my solution was incorrect but the reason was not told to me. Looking for some help in identifying the bug.

Comment: Hard to tell what was wrong with the code without seeing it!

Comment: i have attached the code as an image. It was not allowing me to upload the code as is because of formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

According to your question,Lets introduce the integer being considered as 'X'.

- All items in list 'a' are factors of  'X'
- 'X' is a factor of all items in list 'b'.

First find all factors of items in list b,and then find the common values.The output(item n) will the possible values for 'X'.

Then find the factors for those possible values. If the items in the list 'a' is a subset of the factor values of possible value list, the possible value(item n) will be selected for the final list.These values are 'X' values.I have provide my code as a sample answer.

```
n,m=raw_input().split()
a = map(int,raw_input().split())
b = map(int,raw_input().split())

#Find factors for the list b items and store in (dictionary)dct
dct={}
for i in b:
    dct[i]=[]
for i in range (0,int(m)):
    for j in range(1,int(b[i])+1):
        if int(b[i])%j==0:
            dct[(b[i])].append(j)

#Find all factor values which are common for all key items. 
selct = None
for k,v in dct.items():
    if selct == None:
        selct = set( v )
    else:
        selct = selct.intersection( set(v) )
select1 = list( selct )
#The 'select1' contains all the common factors.
#[8, 1, 2, 4, 16]
#These are the possible values for 'X'.

#Then again find all the factor values for select list items.
dct2={}
for i in select1:
    dct2[i]=[]

for i in range (0,len(select1)):
    for j in range(1,int(select1[i])+1):
        if int(select1[i])%j==0:
            dct2[(select1[i])].append(j)

#{8: [1, 2, 4, 8], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 4: [1, 2, 4], 16: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]}
#If the values of list a is a subset of values of dct2,
#the key value is a matching value for 'X'.
final=[]
for k,v in dct2.items():
    if(set(a).issubset(v)):
        final.append(k)
print len(final)
```